# Set of residue classes under modulo 3 multiplication does not form a group?

Tags: finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

I see that the set of residue classes under modulo 3 multiplication operation satisfy closure, associativity property, commutative property, the existence of identity but does not satisfy the existence of inverse.

set of residue classes of modulo 3 = {$0,1,2$}

$0$={$...-6,-3,0,3,6....$}

$1$={$...-5,-2,1,4,7...$}

$2$={$....-4,-1,2,5,8...$}

Existence of inverse $a*a'=a'*a=e$.

The identity element being $e= 1$

Every element in the set of residues $modulo 3$ has an inverse except $0$ as $0 mod 3$ does not have an inverse.

So is it right to say the set of residues classes under modulo 3 multiplication does not form a group?

I cannot find any source that explicitly answers my question hence it posting here.

Comment: Yes, $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse in integers modulo $3$, so integers modulo $3$ do not form a group under multiplication

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Are you certain that is what is being asked?  Are you sure you are not beings asked if the *non-zero* residue classes form a group? You are correct the set of *all* residue classes do *not* form a group under multiplication.  But  the set of *non-zero* residue classes $\mod 3$ **DO**. (It is equivalent to the group $\{e,a\}$ where $e=\{..,-2,1,4,...\}$ and $a=\{...,-1,2,5,...\}$ where $e*e=a; e*a=a*e=a;a*a=e$ )

Comment: Yes, the question nowhere mentions the word "non zero". It just asks "Does the set of residue classes modulo 3 form a group under multiplication operation"

Comment: Then you are 100% correct for exactly the right reasons.  For any modulo $k$ (assuming $k> 1$) you we always have $0\times a \equiv 0\pmod k$ and $1\times a \equiv a\pmod k$ so $1$ is always an identity under multiplication and there will never a multiplicative inverse for $0$.  So *all* the residue classes will never be a group.  But *sometimes* (not always) if we omit the $0$ residue class the remaining often are a group.  These will be very important (and fun) later.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Yes, indeed there is no inverse for 0 mod k under multiplication operation.